# I'm getting Name error for my python class attributes

Tags: python, class, nameerror

I've just started learning Python and I was trying out class concept and came across this error and cant find out what I've done wrong ! Can someone point out ?!

```
class animal:
    def __init__(self,name,ani,age,location):
        self.name= name
        self.ani = ani
        self.age = age
        self.location = location

    def info(self):
        print("I'm a {0} called {1} and I'm {2} years old, living in {3}".format(ani,name,age,location))


Arun = animal(Martin,Dog,7,Amazon)
Arun.info()
```

And the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\class_trail.py", line 12, in <module>
Arun = animal(Martin,Dog,7,Amazon) NameError: name 'Martin' is not defined
```

Comment: You missed `self.` before the varaible names and quotations marks around the strings.

Comment: Oh Yeah! opps. Thankyou ! Its all fine now

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of things have gone wrong with your code:

1. You are passing in variable names, not strings.

When you call `Arun = animal(Martin,Dog,7,Amazon)`, Python looks for a variable name called Martin, but doesn't find one and raises `NameError`.

What you probably intended was `Arun = animal('Martin','Dog',7,'Amazon')`

2. Your .info() method needs to refer to self.ani and self.age etc., because those data items are bound up inside the object.

Comment: Thankyou for the time ! I''m still trying to figure out where to use self and where not to , Its kinda confusing ! Code is working fine now

Comment: @ArunPrakash your __init__ method and the fact that you call info(self) should give you a clue about that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Arun = animal(Martin,Dog,7,Amazon)
```

^ you want to pass here string values, but instead you're passing there variables which are not defined. To pass there strings you have to wrap them into quotes like this:

```
Arun = animal("Martin","Dog",7,"Amazon")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting refers to the fact that no variable `Martin` is defined in the code, before you use it. What you probably meant to do is

```
Arun = animal("Martin", "Dog", 7, "Amazon")
```

Note the quotes around the strings you are passing as parameters, as opposed to how python interprets your code, where this would work:

```
name = "Martin"
animal = "Dog"
age = 7
location = "Amazon"

Arun = animal(name, animal, age, location)
```

Extra: something you may want to get used to while learning to code in Python are its good practices. Python classes are typically declared with a capital letter (or actually PascalCase), like so `class Animal():`, while variable names are typically declared lower case (snake_case), like so `arun = Animal(...)`.

There is a small exception: constants are declared all capital, like so `EULER_CONSTANT = 0.577`.

Comment: Yeah ! Thankyou for the help, just starting out with programming, hence these funny mistakes.

Comment: Yes, it's part of it! Check out my last edit, it will help you conforming to Python best practices and make collaborating with others smoother.